# Appearing UISwitch in wrong cell of UITableView

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have no UISwitch in my first cell, but after scrolling it suddenly appears and I don’t understand why?!!

I would appreciate some advise or even better some coding ideas!

Thank you!

**Screenshots**
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qxoc0yidpzxkfgv/gLra_Ilsuv

--

**my code**

```c#
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    SettingObject *settingObjectCell = [[[settingsItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"SectionItems"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Selected row - custiomize
    UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    // add UISwitcher
    if ([settingObjectCell.switcher isEqualToString:@"YES"] || [settingObjectCell.switcher isEqualToString:@"NO"])

    {

        UISwitch *switcher = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        //place for switcher
        cell.accessoryView = switcher;


        // load settings or get default
        NSString *switchYesNo = [settingsLoadedUserDefault objectForKey:[settingObjectCell title]] ? [settingsLoadedUserDefault objectForKey:[settingObjectCell title]] : settingObjectCell.switcher ;

        // add value to switcher
        [switcher setOn:[switchYesNo boolValue]];

        // action for switcher
        [switcher addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        // selection Turn OFF
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [settingObjectCell title];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [settingObjectCell subtitle];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's the type of switcher property in settingObjectCell.switcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the switcher is type of NSString you should use isEqualToString: instead of isEqual:.
Change your if statement to:

```
if ([settingObjectCell.switcher isEqualToString:@"YES"] || [settingObjectCell.switcher isEqualToString:@"NO"])
{
    // Your existing code
}
else
{
    //Move this line here
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    // remove switch
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
}
```

The issue happens because of reuse cell you have to clear the cell (remove switch) when you don't need it.
It should work.

Comment: You're right with "isEqualToString", but it still have the same problem. :(

Comment: Have you got just one table view section? Is your switch variable uppercase YES or NO?

Comment: I have got many sections. Yes, my swtich variable has uppercase YES or NO (NSString).

Comment: See my edited post. I haven't notice that you have multiple section.

Comment: Thank You so much. It works!!! When I will have more reputation points l'll vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your cell on the `prepareForReuse` method. When you dequeue the cell from the tableview, the cell is not reset and the old values are still on the cell!

Comment: Can you explain it with some coding example?

Comment: Maybe should I replace [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier] with different method? but which?